# Cartesian coordinate system (x,y,z) in function of (r,θ,x)

Tags: vector-fields

How would you (initially) approach solving this (by hand):

> Consider the vector field 
>   $$F(x,y,z) = \left(0, \frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}, \frac{z}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\right).$$
>   In cylindrical coordinates this vector field is given $F(r,\theta,x)=(1,0,0)$.
>
> What is the Cartesian coordinate system $(x,y,z)$ in function of $(r,\theta,x)$?

Comment: I’ve converted your text to MathJax; please review some of our [tutorials](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for using it in the future.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: What’s $F$ got to do with anything here? The question at the end is simply asking about how to convert from cylindrical to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Hi, I assumed it was F to represent the vector 'field'. The conversion from cylindrical to cartesian scares me. It's converting from 3d to 2d, right? And I should do: x = r cos θ, y = r sin θ, z = z, is that right?